# xpath /descendant-or-self - Searching for a node in a particular tree

Tags: xml, xpath, tree, descendant

I am reading about the short-cut, '//', which apparently is a shortcut for:

'/descendant-or-self'

it is clear what to expect, say, from a simple example of such an expression, 
eg,

//myNode

It will return a node list of all instances in the document, found from the root, of elements called 'myNode'.

However, what is the meaning of a more complicated expression, such as:

//aNode//myNode

?

Since // (being the shortcut for '/descendant-or-self') matches the root node twice, 
does this mean the first part of the expression '//aNode' is redundant, and only adds to the time it takes to complete the execution of the expression (after having still only found all expressions throughout the whole document, of 'myNode') ?

Are  '//myNode' and '//aNode//myNode' going to result in exactly the same thing?

Finally, if I was searching through the document for an instance of node 'myNode' which was an indirect descendant of node 'interestingTree'. But I don't want the instance of node 'myNode' which is an indirect descendant of node 'nonInterestingTree', 
how should I do this ?

for example, searching in the document:

```
<root>
    <anode>
        <interestingTree>
            <unknownTree>
                <myNode/><!-- I want to find this one, not the other, where I don't know the path indicated by 'unknownTree' -->
            </unknownTree>
        </interestingTree>
        <nonInterestingTree>
            <unknownTree>
                <myNode/>
            </unknownTree>
        </nonInterestingTree>
    </anode>
    <anode>
        <someOtherNode/>
    </anode>
</root>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are '//myNode' and '//aNode//myNode' going to result in exactly the same thing?

Yes, in this case, because all `myNodes` are also descendants of `anode`. In the general sense however, `//aNode//myNode` will obviously not match nodes which do not have an `anode` parent in their ancestor tree.

The xpath:

```
//aNode//myNode
```

will ignore any intermediate hierarchy between `aNode` and `myNode`, i.e. it will match `/aNode/myNode`, `/anyNodes/anode/myNode`, and `/anyNodes/anode/xyzNode/myNode`

Which answers your last question, you can find the nodes in the interesting subpath like so: (and again, ignoring any intermediate elements in the hierarchy)

```
//anode//interestingTree//myNode
```

ideally of course, you should be as explicit as possible with your pathing, as `//` can incur performance overhead due to the potentially large number of elements it needs to search.

**Edit** Possibly this helps?

I've adjusted your xml input for clarity to:

```
<root>
    <anode>
        <interestingTree>
            <unknownTree>
                <myNode>
                    MyNode In Interesting Tree
                </myNode>
            </unknownTree>
        </interestingTree>
        <nonInterestingTree>
            <unknownTree>
                <myNode>
                    MyNode In Non-Interesting Tree
                </myNode>
            </unknownTree>
        </nonInterestingTree>
    </anode>
    <anode>
        <someOtherNode/>
    </anode>
    <bnode>
        <myNode>
            MyNode in BNode
        </myNode>
    </bnode>
</root>
```

When parsed through the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        Matched by `//myNode`
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//myNode">
        </xsl:apply-templates>

        Matched by `//aNode//myNode`
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//anode//myNode">
        </xsl:apply-templates>

        Matched by `//aNode//interestingTree//myNode`
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//anode//interestingTree//myNode">
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="myNode">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Returns the following:

```
Matched by `//myNode`
        MyNode In Interesting Tree
        MyNode In Non-Interesting Tree
    MyNode in BNode

Matched by `//aNode//myNode`
        MyNode In Interesting Tree
        MyNode In Non-Interesting Tree

Matched by `//aNode//interestingTree//myNode`
        MyNode In Interesting Tree
```

Comment: So, while in my testing i've discovered //aNode == "/descendant-or-self::aNode" (and importantly NOT "descendant-or-self::aNode") ,
we can nonetheless be sure that the second component of the xpath expression "//aNode//myNode" will only ever be a descendant of 'aNode'  ?

Comment: @svaens Updated - hopefully clarifies?

Comment: yes, thank you! Got it. Though the syntax is surprising, considering how '//' means '/descendant-or-self' and not simply  'descendant-or-self'

Comment: `//` is nothing more or less than a textual shorthand for `/descendant-or-self::node()/` (including the leading and trailing slashes), so `//aNode//myNode` means `/descendant-or-self::node()/aNode/descendant-or-self::node()/myNode`.  If the `//` occurs at the beginning of a path it will anchor at the root, if it occurs anywhere else it will anchor at the current place (in particular `.//myNode` refers to a `myNode` descendant of the current node, not the root).

Comment: @svaens If you just 'expand' it out, e.g. `//aNode//myNode` to `/descendant-or-self::node()/anode/descendant-or-self::node()/myNode`, it becomes more clear that `//` will only 'start' at the root node if there is no node before the `//`?

Comment: @Ian Roberts  thanks! Now I have really got it!

Can anyone recommend a GOOD book? I have a book somewhere ( I forget which one... for XSLT I think, it has an XPath section in it) but it is not very thorough. And I have not found a website which explained it quite as clear as that.

Answer (score 1):

You ask "Are '//myNode' and '//aNode//myNode' going to result in exactly the same thing?"

Not necessarily.  The first will return all elements named `myNode` in the document; the second will return all elements named `myNode` that occur as descendants of elements named `aNode`.  In your example XML, those two descriptions happen to define the same set, but in some XML documents they won't.

The expressions `//aNode//myNode` and `//myNode[ancestor::aNode]`, on the other hand, will always return the same set of nodes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes, I realized after I posted,that my example was not the best. In fact, I had asked my question first 'generally', and then only part of my question was referring to the example XML document (but i had unfortunately not made that as clear as it could have been).